# Does anyone know of midrashim on the number of times the word "or" (light) appears during Creation?

Tags: midrash, creation

I'm reading a work by a contemporary Jewish author who has some midrashic inspiration, however vague. I came across a passage that attempts to impute significance to the number of times "light" is referenced in Genesis before it is named "day" (5 times). I can't think of an echt midrashic source that explores this issue, which leads me to believe that the interpretation in the aforementioned text, while loosely rabbinically-evocative, is in fact original. I'm curious if anyone else can think of precursors in the tradition itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you count **א֑וֹר Or** (5-times) with gematria , you could write (207 x 5) =  **1,035**. | This could represent the minutes adding up to a Day.

We find [Bereishit 1:1-5](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165/jewish/Chapter-1.htm) shows **"Light" | א֑וֹר Or** (5-times), before "Day" | י֔וֹם Yom.

Light #1 + Light #2 in Bereishit 1:3 "And God said, "Let there be **light**," and there was **light**." (וַיֹּ֥אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֖ים יְהִי־**א֑וֹר** וַֽיְהִי־**אֽוֹר**)

Light #3 + Light #4 in Bereishit 1:4 "And God saw the **light** that it was good, and God separated between the **light** and between the darkness." (וַיַּ֧רְא אֱלֹהִ֛ים אֶת־הָ**א֖וֹר** כִּי־ט֑וֹב וַיַּבְדֵּ֣ל אֱלֹהִ֔ים בֵּ֥ין הָ**א֖וֹר** וּבֵ֥ין הַחֽשֶׁךְ)

Light #5 in Bereishit 1:5 "And God called the **light** 'Day', and the darkness He called 'Night', and it was evening and it was morning, one day." (וַיִּקְרָ֨א אֱלֹהִ֤ים | לָאוֹר֙ י֔וֹם וְלַח֖שֶׁךְ קָ֣רָא לָ֑יְלָה וַֽיְהִי־עֶ֥רֶב וַֽיְהִי־בֹ֖קֶר י֥וֹם אֶחָֽד)

Comment: There are 1440 minutes in a day, though. Are you citing a drash or offering your own?

Comment: Offering my own.